# find a host name of a website

Tags: dns, hosting, nameservers

I just reported an abuse on a website that Infringing on my trademark. when I used "Who is" service to find out the host of this domain name and/or the registrar company I got these DNS information:

```
Name Server: ns1.name.com
Name Server: ns2.name.com
Name Server: ns3.name.com
Name Server: ns4.name.com
```

When I reported an abuse on **name.com** they sent me a reply telling me that they don't host this domain and they cant do anything to help me and they told me to use any "Who is" service to find out the correct host of this domain!!!.
Is this possible, I mean the DNS refers to their server!. Any Help Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this site for finding hosting info. it may works, but i am not sure. the link is

=>www.scamadviser.
com

using this site you will find all informatin of a website